# Number of 'x' chars in a string - Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm practicing pretty basic recursion problems in Java.

*"Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) the number of lowercase 'x' chars in the string"*

```
countX("xxhixx") → 4

countX("xhixhix") → 3

countX("hi") → 0
```

-

```
 public int countX(String str) {
      if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return 0;
      else if (str.length() == 1)
        return str.charAt(0) == 'x' ? 1 :0;
      else {
        return (str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'x' ? 1 : 0 ) + countX(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
      }
    }
```

This works fine. But, I would like to know if there is any better way of writing it. I find this code complex for a simple problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason you think this is cumbersome is that it is. A recursive solution is just generally not optimal for counting things in a string or array. Besides the fact that the code looks strange, at least to me, you are actually creating a new stack frame and a new version of the string for every character. This is inefficient (although I wonder if `String.substring` is optimized to point to the original buffer instead of making a full copy, given that strings are immutable).

However, given the constraints of your problem, you could probably get rid of a few redundant checks that you do in your code:

```
public int countX(String str) {
    if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    return (str.charAt(0) == 'x' ? 1 : 0) + countX(str.substring(1));
```

Since you already test for `null` and empty strings, a string of length 1 is no longer a special case.

By removing the first character at each iteration instead of the last, you make the indexing and the call to `substring` much cleaner. This also removes two explicit calls to `str.length()`.

Answer (score 1):

The special treatment for a string of length 1 is redundant - it's already covered by the `else` clause:

```
public int countX(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    }
    return (str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'x' ? 1 : 0 ) + 
           countX(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks more clear ?

```
public static int countX(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count = 0;
        if (str.charAt(0) == 'x') {
            count++;
        }
        return count + countX(str.substring(1));
    }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you choose `count++` over `count = 1`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Just matter of style. No difference :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public int countX(String str) {
  if (str == null)
    return 0;
  else {
        int occurrence = str.lastIndexOf("x");
        int count = occurrence > -1 ? 1 + countX(str.substring(0, occurrence)) : 0;

        return count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `else if (str.length() == 1)` is not necessary as this condition is already been handled by the `return (str.charAt(...`

I don't think it can be improved more than that. Actually, I think the problem is too simple to use recursion (using a loop would be pretty much simpler, but as you can't use it...) and the code would be more complicated than needed anyway.